# Why can't I connect to my project portal with my newly created teamsystem user?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I've followed this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243134(VS.80).aspx) to create a new user in TFS and add it to the Administrator group

When I try to connect to my project portal (directly from the tfs computer), it asks for my credentials :

- if I enter my new user's
  credentials, IIS says "Access
  Denied"
- if I try to log in using the windows Administrator account, it
  works fine.

I'm a bit puzzled here. Do I need to grant access to my user account somewhere else? (like in IIS for example?)

Additional info :
I'm using TFS sp1, on windows server 2008 + sql server 2008.
My user account has been created as a standard user on the server (I've tried to upgrade it to an Admin user just in case, but this doesn't work either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming by "project portal" you mean the Sharepoint server?  Is this TFS in "workgroup mode" (meaning the 5 user limit edition?)  If so, you'd need to add the user to the Licensed Users group in TFS.

If not, I would check that the user has the right permissions in Sharepoint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252449(VS.80).aspx